# Как правильно создать query builder scope все последующие вызови которого вернут пустую коллекцию?

Tags: php, laravel

Использую Laravel query builder scope

```
       function someScope() {  
          if (is_null($searchText) || strlen($searchText) === 0) {
              return self::where('id', 'текст чтобы вернул пустую коллекцию потому что id не может быть равен этому тексту');
          }
```

последующий вызов  `$someModel->someScope()->orWhere(["some statement"])`  вернет  пустую коллекцию что и требовалось, вопрос в том что  как сделать условие

`self::where('id', 'some text');`  более правильным, то есть как создать query scope  вызов которого не смотря на любые последующие условия вернул бы пустую коллекцию ?

Comment: Может я что то не понял, может where('id', -1)

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Да  такое решение возможно `where('id', false)` , только думаю найти более чистое решение может быть в Laravel уже оно есть ?

Comment: Скорее всего нет, в любом случае неправильно реализовывать данную логику в Scope, они предназначены для глобальных условий. Я бы посоветовал использовать репозиторий для данного функционала